# Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.googleapis.com:443 PHP google anaytlics api

Tags: php, ssl, curl, google-analytics-api

I am using the google anaytlics api, I am querying how many visits 100 sites have, this process takes around 6 minutes or so. The problem is that it runs some of the results until it comes up with the following error.

Uncaught exception 'apiIOException' with message 'HTTP Error: (0) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.googleapis.com:443

I am using oauth 2.0 key , I have increased my user requests per second on the api console still with no luck. It must be something to do with the SSL, I just dont have a clue why.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to help without seeing some code ...

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because of request limits.

10 queries per second (QPS) per IP address.
In the API Console, there is a similar quota referred to as Requests per 100 seconds per user. By default, it is set to 100 requests per 100 seconds per user and can be adjusted to a maximum value of 1,000. But the number of requests to the API is restricted to a maximum of 10 requests per second per user.

You can find more information from [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas).